# How joining two Polygon_with_holes_2 on cgal

Tags: c++, graphics, cgal

I have two polygons (Polygon_with_holes_2)
how joining it into thirth Polygon_with_holes_2

I need general solution. Get any polygon_with_holes (or not if empty hole list but still polygon_with_holes structures) and joining it with other and get polygon_with_holes. How check orientation (cgal not can joining if it not good), reducing points etc. How to do this with good code without memory leak.

Comment: Have you tried to read any sort of documentation, https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Boolean_set_operations_2/group__boolean__join.html and without your code you are expecting us to be Yoda!!

Comment: @Frrank on docummentation no exist any example with Polygon_with_holes_2 If You clever show me.

Comment: At least in [this example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Boolean_set_operations_2/Boolean_set_operations_2_2symmetric_difference_8cpp-example.html) boolean operation is done on polygon with holes.

Comment: @sloriot You are clever.Thanks, I search this a few day. I cant vote Your ansver, sorry

Comment: How defining Polygon_with_holes_2 without any holes? Empty?      Polygon_2 outP;
  Polygon_2 holesP[1];
  outP.push_back (Point_2 (0, 0));.... 4 point
  Polygon_with_holes_2  P (outP, holesP, holesP + 1);
i get Explanation: Holes of the PWH intersect amongst themselves or with outer boundary
Refer to the bug-reporting instructions at http://www.cgal.org/bug_report.html
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CGAL::Precondition_exception'
  what():  CGAL ERROR: precondition violation!
Expr: is_valid_unknown_polygon(p, t)

Comment: @Please share the code that show how you are creating the polygon. Then we can talk about boolean on the polygon.